# How to notify a Zend 3 controller about an MVC error event?

Tags: php, zend-framework3

In a Zend 3 application,when occurres an error, I need a custom controller to be notified about this. What is unclear is where and how could I notify it or to dispatch this error event to it.

The error controller is an extension of

```
abstract class AbstractActionController
```

interface and has a couple of **action** functions:

```
class ErrorController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function errorAction(){
        ...
        return new ViewModel();
    }
    public function invalidUserAction(){
        ...
        return new ViewModel();
    }
    public function autheticationFailureAction(){
        ...
        return new ViewModel();
    }
    public function timedoutAction() {
        ...
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried thus far? What errors did you encounter? Did you read up on the `EventManager` in ZF3? What did you (not) understand on its usage? Have you tried to apply any of the other Answers about near-similar questions on SO? Did you encounter any difficulty with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen mvc event then trigger your controller. I assume you are trying to show different pages for different errors. Actually you can make it with a listener method only. You don't need a controller. Checkout zfcrbac's unauthorized error listener.